# What is the Cloudflare equivalent of these two .htaccess redirect rules?

Tags: htaccess, redirects, https, mod-rewrite, cloudflare

I usually set up my sites to rewrite URLs in the following cases:

1. All http traffic is redirected to https (and www), with a 301
2. All non-www traffic is redirected to www (and https), with a 301

In .htaccess, the rewrite rules are as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Note that all redirects are achieved with only one hop.  Non-www traffic goes to www *and* https, and non-https traffic goes to https *and* www.  How do you achieve the same results in Cloudflare?

P.S. I'm not sure if Cloudflare's "Always Use HTTPS" option is worth enabling since it doesn't use a 301 and I have to write a separate rule for a https redirect rule with a 301 anyway.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.bybe.net/cloudflare-enforce-ssl-redirect-http-https/ has the full details.

To redirect to HTTPS, you need add a "Page Rule" for `http://*example.com/*` with the "Always Use HTTPS" option from the settings.

To redirect to `www` you need three "Page Rules":

- `http://example.com/*` -> `https://www.example.com/$1`
- `https://example.com/*` -> `https://www.example.com/$1`
- `http://www.example.com/*` -> `https://www.example.com/$1`

---

Alternately, you could just leave your *.htaccess* rules in place.  You rule for the `http_host` should continue to work unmodified, even post-CloudFlare because CloudFlare should forward the `Host: example.com` header.   You would just need to chang the condition on your  HTTPS rule to use the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header that CloudFlare sets to let you know if the request was http or https.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} http
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: So you're saying it can't be done with the free tier, since that only includes 3 rules.

Comment: If that is the case, no need to pay for a tier because of this.  I added an alternative to my answer.